# Find highlighted text and output page text is on

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to search a document and output a box that tells the user what page highlighted text is on.

What I came up, on a smaller document (32 pages, 5719 words), runs in about 15 seconds with an error in the output. It tells me that there are highlights on page 3 and 4.
Page 3 contains part of my Table of Contents and I can't find anything highlighted on it. I even looked for hidden text.
Page 4 did have highlighting.

When I run it on a larger document it freezes and crashes Word. I waited 5 minutes it never recovered (55 pages, 10086 words).

The portion I am struggling with:

```
' Search for highlighted text and call it out
Dim hlpagenums As String
Dim rng As Range
hlpagenums = ""
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
Set rng = Selection.Range
With rng.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Format = True
    .Highlight = True
    Do While .Execute(Forward:=True, Format:=True)
        hlpagenums = hlpagenums & rng.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber) & ", "
        rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Loop
End With
If hlpagenums <> "" Then
    hlpagenums = Left(hlpagenums, Len(hlpagenums) - 2)
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.Find.Format = True
    Selection.Find.Highlight = True
    Selection.Find.Execute
    MsgBox "Highlighted text found on page(s): " & hlpagenums
End If
```

My CPU doesn't even hit 10% when it freezes.

Comment: It's notoriously [difficult to work with pages in Word](https://shaunakelly.com/word/word-development/selecting-or-referring-to-a-page-in-the-word-object-model.html) especially when you have Tables or Fields (which a Table Of Contents is) overlapping page boundaries. Having read that article, if you still want to try and do this, I'd suggest stepping through your code (i.e. with F8) to see if `Find` is matching some piece of highlighted text infinitely or, the other reason for taking a long time, might be the call to `.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)`

Answer (score 2):

Use a `dictionary` to get unique page numbers. Takes 2.8s for 40 pages Word document (9K words, 10 Highlight on each page).

```vb
Sub FinDHL()
    Dim hlpagenums As Long
    Dim oRng As Range
    Dim oDic As Object, t
    t = Timer
    Set oDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Content
    With oRng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Format = True
        .Highlight = True
        Do While .Execute(Forward:=True, Format:=True)
            hlpagenums = oRng.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
            If Not oDic.Exists(hlpagenums) Then oDic(hlpagenums) = ""
            oRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With
    Debug.Print Join(oDic.keys, ",")
    Debug.Print Timer - t
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice... Voted if up. It can be easily adapted to also place each highlighted `Text` in its page, as dictionary item.